# Why can't I reuse an event even after explicit ResetEvent call?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to watch for changes done with a file (the event i'm waiting for is change contents event, i.e. last modified date is updated)

I have a code like this (minimalized example of actual code)
I expect that each iteration of the while loop the event gets reset and is available to be fired again but that doesn't happen
Why it fires change event only once?

```cpp
int main()
{
    const wchar_t *dir_path = L"C:\\Users\\IC\\AppData\\Roaming\\JetBrains\\CLion2021.3\\scratches\\";

    HANDLE hDir = ::CreateFileW(
        dir_path,
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL
    );

    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION fni;
    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    overlapped.hEvent = ::CreateEventA(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

    ::ReadDirectoryChangesW(
        hDir,
        &fni,
        sizeof(fni),
        TRUE,
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE,
        NULL,
        &overlapped,
        NULL
    );

    while (true)
    {
        std::vector<HANDLE> all_job_event_handles;
        if (::ResetEvent(overlapped.hEvent) == FALSE)
        {
            printf("ResetEvent failed\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            return 1;
        }
        all_job_event_handles.push_back(overlapped.hEvent);

        DWORD result = ::WaitForMultipleObjects(all_job_event_handles.size(), all_job_event_handles.data(), FALSE, INFINITE);
        if (result == WAIT_FAILED)
        {
            printf("WaitForMultipleObjects failed\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            return 1;
        }

        if (result >= WAIT_OBJECT_0 && result < WAIT_OBJECT_0 + all_job_event_handles.size())
        {
            printf("file changed\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's just not how `ReadDirectoryChanges` works. It doesn't continuously send you changes. It sends you one batch of changes. You process them. You call the function again to tell the system that you want more changes.

I found a correct usage example of the function here: https://gist.github.com/nickav/a57009d4fcc3b527ed0f5c9cf30618f8

Some side notes:

- You don't check whether `ReadDirectoryChanges` succeeds. This is bad; if it failed, you will hang on the Wait call forever.
- You don't zero-initialize the `OVERLAPPED` structure.
- You create the event as an auto-reset event (second parameter is `FALSE`). `ResetEvent` on such an event does nothing.
- All the event handles you add into your vector are the same event object. You just have an ever-growing list of the same event repeatedly that you pass to `WaitForMultipleObjects`. This does nothing at best, but will eventually fail because `WFMO` doesn't allow more than `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` handles, and this number is fairly low (32, I think).
- You probably want a more permissive share mode on the directory you open.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and side notes. Most of the notes are just issues of porting of my actual code to a minimal reproducible example. ReadDirectoryChanges is what i need to call in my loop, thanks

Comment: Couldn't you please also note, is it enough to have just a single `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` variable or it should be an array?

Comment: An array seems better.

Comment: "*`WFMO` doesn't allow more than `MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS` handles, and this number is fairly low (32, I think)*" - actually, it is 64. That doesn't mean you can't wait on more than 64 objects, though. You just have to get a little more creative with the waits.

Comment: @IC_ you should use an array of `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION`. The more records `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` can return at a time, the better. However, you are waiting on a single `HANDLE`, so you don't need the `vector<HANDLE>` at all, that is just wasting memory. You can pass that single `HANDLE` directly to `WaitForMultipleObjects()` (ie, `WaitForMultipleObjects(1, &(overlapped.hEvent), FALSE, INFINITE)`), or just use `WaitForSingleObject()` instead (ie, `WaitForSingleObject(overlapped.hEvent, INFINITE)`)

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for pointing out. As i said it's a crude chopped piece of actual code. In the actual code i need to handle changes from multiple directories